# Android - FATAL EXCEPTION: main when adding subList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, sublist

I'm currently working on my first Android application.
It parses JSON Data and puts it in a ListView (see below).

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                listItems.add(json.getJSONObject(i).getString(("title")));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, when adding a subList by changing the function to this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

            List subList = listItems.subList(1,3);

            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                listItems.add(json.getJSONObject(i).getString(("title")));
                subList.add("Test");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It generates the following error:

```
03-03 14:23:56.480  15414-15414/nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden, PID: 15414
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.util.AbstractList.subList(AbstractList.java:738)
        at nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden.Main$HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Main.java:133)
        at nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden.Main$HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Main.java:117)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 List subList = listItems.subList(1,3);
```

if `listItems`, is empty or has less than four elements subList throws `IndexOutBoundException`. To be more precise it throws `IndexOutBoundException` when `(fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)`.

Edit:

> I would like to put the title in the "Normal" list, and the date of
>   the message in the sublist like this:

you can use a class, with two public fields, title and subtitle for this purpose. E.g.

```
 public class Information {
    public String mTitle;
    public String mSubtitle;
 }
```

and in your for-loop you could have:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
     Information tmp = new Information();
     tmp.mTitle = son.getJSONObject(i).getString(("title"));
     tmp.mSubtitle = "..";
     listItems.add(tmp);
  }
```

of course you have to change your list accordingly to accept objects of type `Information`. In this case all the info you need are hold by the information object, reducing those kind of issues

Comment: Alright, that explains a lot, thanks. But now, however, I'm not really sure how I actually need to add the subList itself. Could you explain that?

Comment: why do you need a sublist?

Comment: I would like to put the title in the "Normal" list, and the date of the message in the sublist like this: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/img/main_sub_list.png)

Comment: I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.. I have edited my ArrayList from `ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();` to `ArrayList<Information> listItems = new ArrayList<Information>();` But now my Adapter is throwing errors: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);`. "Cannot resolve constructor" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Information>(..)` now, and probably you will also wanto to learn how to have a custom getView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72153/discussion-between-kaanmijo-and-blackbelt).